# Numpy efficient way to get number of unique intersecting intervals

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, pandas

I've a data frame with intervals like

```
start end
1     10
3     7
8     10
```

and I need to find number of intersections with the other data frame

```
value
2
5
9
```

result should be

```
1
2
2
```

The seconds part of question is more tricky.
My data frame with intervals contains also kind of `type`

```
start end type
1     10  1
3     7   1
8     10  2
```

And I need to know many unique(by type) interval will be intersected. Result should be:

```
1
1
2
```

I guess the first part can be done by `numpy.searchsorted` but what's about the second one?

Comment: In the second row the type is 1. If the value in the other data frame is 5, then both [1,10] and [3,7] are intersected. So shouldn't the result (i.e. the number of unique intervals intersected) be `[1,2,2]` rather than `[1,1,2]`?

Comment: If you did the first part and showed us your code, it would be easier to help you with the second part.

Comment: @unutbu both [1,10] and [3,7] are of the same type (type 1), so there is only one type of interval that 5 intersects. It's not unique intervals but unique types.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your first dataframe `df`. For a given value, intersecting intervals can be found as such:

```
mask = (df['start'] <= value) & (df['end'] >= value)
```

The following will return the number of intersecting intervals:

```
mask.sum()
```

The following will return the number of intersecting types:

```
len(df['type'][mask].unique())
```

Now you can `apply` a lambda function to the values series:

```
values = pd.Series([2, 5, 9], name=['value'])
values.apply(lambda value: len(df['type'][(df['start'] <= value) & (df['end'] >= value)].unique()))
```

Comment: I'm concerned about efficiency of you code. Can it be implemented in 100% broadcasted way?

Answer (score 1):

DSM shows [a great way to deal with intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773404/190597) using Pandas. Following that pattern, we can combine the `start`  and `end` values into a single column of `idx`s with a second column (`change`) which equals 1 when the `idx` corresponds to a `start`, and -1 when the `idx` corresponds to an `end`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'end': [10, 7, 10], 'start': [1, 3, 8], 'type': [1, 1, 2]})
event = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['type'], var_name='change', value_name='idx')
event['change'] = event['change'].map({'start':1, 'end':-1})
event = event.sort_values(by=['idx'])
#    type  change  idx
# 3     1       1    1
# 4     1       1    3
# 1     1      -1    7
# 5     2       1    8
# 0     1      -1   10
# 2     2      -1   10
```

Now, since we wish to keep track of the `type` of intervals, we can use `event.pivot`
to place each type in its own column. Taking the `cumsum` counts the number of intervals covering `idx`:

```
event = event.pivot(index='idx', columns='type', values='change').fillna(0).cumsum(axis=0)
# type  1  2
# idx       
# 1     1  0
# 3     2  0
# 7     1  0
# 8     1  1
# 10    0  0
```

For each `type`, we only care about the values which are covered, not how many times it is covered. So let's compute `event > 0` to find the values covered:

```
event = event > 0
# type      1      2
# idx               
# 1      True  False
# 3      True  False
# 7      True  False
# 8      True   True
# 10    False  False
```

Now we can use `searchsorted` to find the desired result:

```
other = pd.DataFrame({'value': [2, 5, 9]})
idx = event.index.searchsorted(other['value'])-1
other['result'] = event.iloc[idx].sum(axis=1).values
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'end': [10, 7, 10], 'start': [1, 3, 8], 'type': [1, 1, 2]})

event = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['type'], var_name='change', value_name='idx')
event['change'] = event['change'].map({'start':1, 'end':-1})
event = event.sort_values(by=['idx'])
event = event.pivot(index='idx', columns='type', values='change').fillna(0).cumsum(axis=0)
event = event > 0
other = pd.DataFrame({'value': [2, 5, 9]})
idx = event.index.searchsorted(other['value'])-1
other['result'] = event.iloc[idx].sum(axis=1).values
print(other)
```

yields

```
   value  result
0      2       1
1      5       1
2      9       2
```

---

To check the correctness of the calculation, let's look at

```
other = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.arange(13)})
```

Then

```
idx = event.index.searchsorted(other['value'])-1
other['result'] = event.iloc[idx].sum(axis=1).values
print(other)
```

yields

```
    value  result
0       0       0
1       1       0   <-- The half-open interval (1, 10] does not include 1
2       2       1
3       3       1
4       4       1
5       5       1
6       6       1
7       7       1
8       8       1   <-- The half-open interval (8, 10] does not include 8
9       9       2
10     10       2
11     11       0
12     12       0
```

Notice that this method of computation treats the `(start, end]` interval as half-open. If you wish to instead use the half-open intervals `[start, end)`, use

```
idx = event.index.searchsorted(other['value'], side='right')-1
```

Comment: I knew we needed unutbu to the rescue :)