# Count Number of Rows GroupBy within a GroupBy Between Two Dates in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

I have a dataframe `df`, which can be created with the following code:

```
import random
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#create test range of dates
rng=pd.date_range(datetime.date(2015,7,15),datetime.date(2015,7,31))
rnglist=rng.tolist()
testpts = range(100,121)
#create test dataframe
d={'jid':[i for i in range(100,121)], 
   'cid':[random.randint(1,2) for _ in testpts],
   'ctid':[random.randint(3,4) for _ in testpts],       
    'stdt':[rnglist[random.randint(0,len(rng))] for _ in testpts]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)[['jid','cid','ctid','stdt']]
df['enddt'] = df['stdt']+timedelta(days=random.randint(2,16))
```

The `df` looks like this:

```
      jid  cid  ctid       stdt      enddt
0   100    1     4 2015-07-28 2015-08-11
1   101    2     3 2015-07-31 2015-08-14
2   102    2     3 2015-07-31 2015-08-14
3   103    1     3 2015-07-24 2015-08-07
4   104    2     4 2015-07-27 2015-08-10
5   105    1     4 2015-07-27 2015-08-10
6   106    2     4 2015-07-24 2015-08-07
7   107    2     3 2015-07-22 2015-08-05
8   108    2     3 2015-07-28 2015-08-11
9   109    1     4 2015-07-20 2015-08-03
10  110    2     3 2015-07-29 2015-08-12
11  111    1     3 2015-07-29 2015-08-12
12  112    1     3 2015-07-27 2015-08-10
13  113    1     3 2015-07-21 2015-08-04
14  114    1     4 2015-07-28 2015-08-11
15  115    2     3 2015-07-28 2015-08-11
16  116    1     3 2015-07-26 2015-08-09
17  117    1     3 2015-07-25 2015-08-08
18  118    2     3 2015-07-26 2015-08-09
19  119    2     3 2015-07-19 2015-08-02
20  120    2     3 2015-07-22 2015-08-05
```

> What I need to do is the following: Count (`cnt`) the number of `jid`
>   that occur by `ctid` by `cid`, for each date(`newdate`) between the
>   `min(stdt)` and `max(enddt)`, where the `newdate` is between the
>   `stdt` and the `enddt`.

That resulting DataFrame should look like (this is just for 1 `cid` with 1 `ctid` using above data)(this would replicate in this case for `cid` 1/`ctid` 4, `cid` 2/`ctid` 3, `cid` 2/`ctid` 4):

```
cid ctid    newdate cnt
1   3   7/21/2015   1
1   3   7/22/2015   1
1   3   7/23/2015   1
1   3   7/24/2015   2
1   3   7/25/2015   3
1   3   7/26/2015   4
1   3   7/27/2015   5
1   3   7/28/2015   5
1   3   7/29/2015   6
1   3   7/30/2015   6
1   3   7/31/2015   6
1   3   8/1/2015    6
1   3   8/2/2015    6
1   3   8/3/2015    6
1   3   8/4/2015    6
1   3   8/5/2015    5
1   3   8/6/2015    5
1   3   8/7/2015    5
1   3   8/8/2015    4
1   3   8/9/2015    3
1   3   8/10/2015   2
1   3   8/11/2015   1
1   3   8/12/2015   1
```

This previous question (which was also mine) [Count # of Rows Between Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772863/count-number-of-rows-between-two-dates-by-id-in-a-pandas-groupby-dataframe/31773404#31773404), was very similar, and was answered using `pd.melt`.  I am pretty sure `melt` can be used again, or maybe there is a better option, but I can't figure out how to get the 'two layer groupby' accomplished which counts the size of `jid` for each `ctid`, for each `cid`, for each `newdate`.  Love your inputs...

Answer (score 1):

After trying @Scott Boston answer, for a 1.8m record df, the first line

```
df_out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(df.iloc[i].stdt,df.iloc[i].enddt)).assign(**df.iloc[i,0:3]) for i in pd.np.arange(df.shape[0])]).reset_index()
```

was still running after 1 hour, and slowly eating away at memory.  So I thought I'd try the following:

```
def reindex_by_date(df):
    dates = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())
    return df.reindex(dates)
def replace_last_0(group):
    group.loc[max(group.index),'change']=0
    return group

def ctidloop(partdf): 
        coid=partdf.cid.max()
        cols=['cid', 'stdt', 'enddt']
        partdf=partdf[cols]
        partdf['jid']=partdf.index
        partdf = pd.melt(partdf, id_vars=['ctid', 'jid'],var_name='change', value_name='newdate')
        partdf['change'] = partdf['change'].replace({'stdt': 1, 'enddt': -1})
        partdf.newdate=pd.DatetimeIndex(partdf['newdate'])
        partdf=partdf.groupby(['ctid', 'newdate'],as_index=False)['change'].sum()
        partdf=partdf.groupby('ctid').apply(replace_last_0).reset_index(drop=True)
        partdf['cnt'] = partdf.groupby('ctid')['change'].cumsum()
        partdf.index=partdf['newdate']
        cols=['ctid', 'change', 'cnt', 'newdate']
        partdf=partdf[cols]
        partdf=partdf.groupby('ctid').apply(reindex_by_date).reset_index(0, drop=True)
        partdf['newdate']=partdf.index
        partdf['ctid']=partdf['ctid'].fillna(method='ffill')
        partdf.cnt=partdf.cnt.fillna(method='ffill')
        partdf.change=partdf.change.fillna(0)
        partdf['cid']=coid
        return partdf
gb=df.groupby('cid').apply(ctidloop)
```

This code returned the correct result in:

```
%timeit gb=df.groupby('cid').apply(ctidloop)
1 loop, best of 3: 9.74 s per loop
```

> EXPLANATION:
>   Basically, `melt` is very quick.  So I figured just break the first `groupby` up into groups and run a function on it.  So This code takes the `df`, then `groupsby` the `cid` and `apply` the function `cidloop`.

In the `cidloop`, the following happens by line:
1) Grab the `cid` for future use.
2,3) establish core `partdf` to process by assigning needed columns
4) create `jid` from the index
5) run the `pd.melt` which flattens the dataframe by creating a row for each `jid` for `stdt` and `enddt`.
6) creates a `'change'` column which assigns +1 to `stdt`, and -1 to `enddt`.
7) makes `newdate` a `datetimeindex` (just easier for further processing)
8) groups what we have by `ctid` and `newdate`, summing the `change`
9) groups by `ctid` again, replacing the last value with 0 (this is just something I needed not specific to the problem)
10) creates `cnt` by group by `ctid` and `cumsumming` the change
11)makes the new index from the `newdate`
12,13) formats columns/names
14) another groupby on `ctid` but reindexing by hi and low dates, filling the gaps.
15) assign `newdate` from the new `reindex` values
16,17,18) fill various values to fill gaps (I needed this enhancement)
19) assign `cid` again from the top variable `coid` gathered in line 1.

Do this for each `cid` through the last line of code `gb=df.groupby.....`

Thanks @Scott Boston for the attempt.  Sure it works but took too long for me.

Kudos to @DSM for his solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772863/count-number-of-rows-between-two-dates-by-id-in-a-pandas-groupby-dataframe/31773404#31773404) which was the basis of my solution.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case with large datasets.  Yours and DSM's solution are best.