# Get deltas for a custom aggregation with date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find an efficient way of creating a query the reports the deltas of an aggregation, with the start and end dates for the value.

**Requirements**

- The source table includes start date, end date, category id, sub category id, and an indicator if the sub category is active.
- The aggregation is for is_active on cat_id, and the result of the function should be 1 as long as any sub_category is also 1 for is_active.
- If results of the aggregate function are the same for consecutive date ranges, then the date ranges should be combined to reduce the result set.
- A category/sub category combination will never have overlapping dates, but other sub categories may cross each other's boundaries.

**What I've Tried**

I tried creating a CTE generating all possible ranges for a category and then joining back to the main query so that a sub category that spans multiple ranges was broken up.  I then grouped by the ranges and did a MAX(is_active).

While this was a good start (all I needed to do at this point was combine consecutive ranges with the same value), the query was extraordinarily slow.  I'm not as familiar with Postgres as I am with other flavors of SQL, and decided my time was better spent reaching out and getting help from someone more experienced.

**Source Data**

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | start_dt   | end_dt     | cat_id | sub_cat_id | is_active | comment                                             |
+----+------------+------------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31 | 1      | 1001       | 1         | (null)                                              |
| 2  | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-14 | 1      | 1001       | 0         | (null)                                              |
| 3  | 2018-02-15 | 2018-02-28 | 1      | 1001       | 0         | cat 1 is_active is unchanged despite new record.    |
| 4  | 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-30 | 1      | 1001       | 1         | (null)                                              |
| 5  | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-15 | 2      | 2001       | 1         | (null)                                              |
| 6  | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31 | 2      | 2002       | 1         | (null)                                              |
| 7  | 2018-01-15 | 2018-02-10 | 2      | 2001       | 0         | cat 2 should still be active until 2002 is inactive |
| 8  | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-14 | 2      | 2002       | 0         | cat 2 is inactive                                   |
| 9  | 2018-02-10 | 2018-03-15 | 2      | 2001       | 0         | this record will cause trouble                      |
| 10 | 2018-02-15 | 2018-03-30 | 2      | 2002       | 1         | cat 2 should be active again                        |
| 11 | 2018-03-15 | 2018-03-30 | 2      | 2001       | 1         | cat 2 is_active is unchanged despite new record.    |
| 12 | 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-30 | 2      | 2001       | 0         | cat 2 ends in a zero                                |
+----+------------+------------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| start_dt   | end_dt     | cat_id | is_active |
+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31 | 1      | 1         |
| 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-28 | 1      | 0         |
| 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-30 | 1      | 1         |
| 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31 | 2      | 1         |
| 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-14 | 2      | 0         |
| 2018-02-15 | 2018-03-30 | 2      | 1         |
| 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-30 | 2      | 0         |
+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

Here's a select statement to help you write your own tests.

```
SELECT id,start_dt::date start_date,end_dt::date end_date,cat_id,sub_cat_id,is_active::int is_active,comment
FROM (VALUES 
    (1, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-31', 1, 1001, '1', null),
    (2, '2018-02-01', '2018-02-14', 1, 1001, '0', null),
    (3, '2018-02-15', '2018-02-28', 1, 1001, '0', 'cat 1 is_active is unchanged despite new record.'),
    (4, '2018-03-01', '2018-03-30', 1, 1001, '1', null),
    (5, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-15', 2, 2001, '1', null),
    (6, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-31', 2, 2002, '1', null),
    (7, '2018-01-15', '2018-02-10', 2, 2001, '0', 'cat 2 should still be active until 2002 is inactive'),
    (8, '2018-02-01', '2018-02-14', 2, 2002, '0', 'cat 2 is inactive'),
    (9, '2018-02-10', '2018-03-15', 2, 2001, '0', 'cat 2 is_active is unchanged despite new record.'),
    (10, '2018-02-15', '2018-03-30', 2, 2002, '1', 'cat 2 should be active agai'),
    (11, '2018-03-15', '2018-03-30', 2, 2001, '1', 'cat 2 is_active is unchanged despite new record.'),
    (12, '2018-04-01', '2018-04-30', 2, 2001, '0', 'cat 2 ends in 0.')

) src ( "id","start_dt","end_dt","cat_id","sub_cat_id","is_active","comment" )
```

Comment: The required logic looks rather convoluted and I haven't tried to understand it all, but you may find the following article by Itzik Ben-Gan helpful: [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/). It is written for SQL Server, but Postgres has all the features it uses (like window functions), so it can be used in Postgres as well.  You may also add some explanations to the question why you end up with this date interval: `2018-02-01 | 2018-02-14` in the expected result for `cat_id = 2`. How did you get those dates?

Comment: I tried to simplify this from the real world problem because that was way too convoluted - maybe I've made it too abstract?  Thanks for the blog post, I will check it out.  To answer your second question, 2018-02-01 - 2018-02-14 is 0 because both subcats 2001 and 2002 are 0 during that period.  At 2018-02-15 2001 is 1 so cat 2 is is_active is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT id, start_dt::date, end_dt::date, cat_id, sub_cat_id, is_active::int, comment  FROM ( VALUES 
        (1, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-31', 1, 1001, '1', null),
        (2, '2018-02-01', '2018-02-14', 1, 1001, '0', null),
        (3, '2018-02-15', '2018-02-28', 1, 1001, '0', 'cat 1 is_active is unchanged despite new record.'),
        (4, '2018-03-01', '2018-03-30', 1, 1001, '1', null),
        (5, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-15', 2, 2001, '1', null),
        (6, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-31', 2, 2002, '1', null),
        (7, '2018-01-15', '2018-02-10', 2, 2001, '0', 'cat 2 should still be active until 2002 is inactive'),
        (8, '2018-02-01', '2018-02-14', 2, 2002, '0', 'cat 2 is inactive'),
        (9, '2018-02-10', '2018-03-15', 2, 2001, '0', 'cat 2 is_active is unchanged despite new record.'),
        (10, '2018-02-15', '2018-03-30', 2, 2002, '1', 'cat 2 should be active agai'),
        (11, '2018-03-15', '2018-03-30', 2, 2001, '1', 'cat 2 is_active is unchanged despite new record.'),
        (12, '2018-04-01', '2018-04-30', 2, 2001, '0', 'cat 2 ends in 0.')
        ) test (id, start_dt, end_dt, cat_id, sub_cat_id, is_active, comment) 
    )
SELECT cat_id, start_date, end_date, active_state
FROM (
    SELECT cat_id, date as start_date, lead(date-1) over w as end_date
        , active_state, prev_active
        , nonactive_state, prev_nonactive
    FROM (
        SELECT cat_id, date 
            , active_state, prev_active
            , nonactive_state
            , lag(nonactive_state, 1, 0) over w as prev_nonactive
        FROM (
            SELECT cat_id, date, active_state, lag(active_state, 1, 0) over w as prev_active
                , (nonactive_state > active_state)::int as nonactive_state
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT ON (cat_id, date)
                    cat_id, date
                    , (CASE WHEN sum(type) over w > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as active_state
                    , (CASE WHEN sum(nonactive_type) over w > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nonactive_state
                FROM (
                    SELECT start_dt as date
                        , 1 as type
                        , cat_id
                        , 0 as nonactive_type
                    FROM test
                    WHERE is_active = 1
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT end_dt + 1 as date
                        , -1 as type
                        , cat_id
                        , 0 as nonactive_type
                    FROM test
                    WHERE is_active = 1
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT start_dt as date
                        , 0 as type
                        , cat_id
                        , 1 as nonactive_type
                    FROM test
                    WHERE is_active = 0
                  UNION ALL
                    SELECT end_dt + 1 as date
                        , 0 as type
                        , cat_id
                        , -1 as nonactive_type
                    FROM test
                    WHERE is_active = 0
                ) t
                WINDOW w as (partition by cat_id order by date)
                ORDER BY cat_id, date
            ) t2
            WINDOW w as (partition by cat_id order by date)
        ) t3
        WINDOW w as (partition by cat_id order by date)
    ) t4
    WHERE (active_state != prev_active) OR (nonactive_state != prev_nonactive)
    WINDOW w as (partition by cat_id order by date)
    ) t5
WHERE active_state = 1 OR nonactive_state = 1
ORDER BY cat_id, start_date
```

yields

```
| cat_id | start_date |   end_date | active_state |
|--------+------------+------------+--------------|
|      1 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31 |            1 |
|      1 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-28 |            0 |
|      1 | 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-30 |            1 |
|      2 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31 |            1 |
|      2 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-14 |            0 |
|      2 | 2018-02-15 | 2018-03-30 |            1 |
|      2 | 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-30 |            0 |
```

---

This combines the `start_dt` and `end_dt` dates into a single column, and
introduces a `type` column which is 1 for start dates and -1 for end dates.
Summing over the `type` produces a value which is positive when the
corresponding `date` is inside a `[start_dt, end_dt]` interval, and which is 0
otherwise.

This is one of the ideas presented in Itzik Ben-Gan's [Packing
Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/), but I first
learned it from DSM (in the context of programming in Python/Pandas)
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31773404/190597).

---

Usually when dealing with intervals using the above technique, the intervals
define when dates are in an "on" state, and being not "on" automatically implies "off".
In this problem, however, it appears 
rows where `active_state = 1` imply the final `active_state` is "on" but dates outside those intervals are not necessarily "off". `2018-03-31` is an example of a date which is outside
the `active_state = 1` intervals but is not "off".
Similarly, rows where `active_state = 0` imply the final `active_state` is "off" so long as the dates do not intersect an interval whose `active_state = 1`.

To handle these two different kinds of intervals, I applied the above technique (summing  +1/-1 `type`s) twice: Once for rows where `is_active = 1` and once for rows where `is_active = 0`.
This gives us a handle on dates which are definitely in an `active_state` ("on") and dates which are definitely in a `nonactive_state` ("off").
Since active trumps nonactive, the dates which are deemed nonactive are trimmed using:

```
(nonactive_state > active_state)::int as nonactive_state
```

(That is, when `active_state = 1` and `nonactive_state = 1`, the assignment above is used to change the `nonactive_state` to `0`.)

Comment: This seems to be skipping some records.  On the two failed examples I checked they both failed when a record existed where the start date and end date were the same.  My bad for not prepping the data with all possible scenarios.

Comment: To keep rows where `start_date` and `end_date` are the same, I've changed `<` to `<=` in `date <= (lead(date) over w)-1`.

Comment: Still issues.  It's missing records where they end with a 0.  Add an addition record 2018-04-01 >for cat 2 where is_active = 0.  No row is returned.

Comment: I didn't get your comment above and didn't understand the significance of skipping 0's before I asked this question.  I tried to simplify the question down to its essence and because of that I omitted data that was essential to the goal. I modified my question above.  Sorry for the time you spent...  This solution would be great as it is quite fast.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the interesting problem. I have to go right now, but I'll think about the problem some more. (I think the issue is fixable, but of course, the proof is in the pudding...)

Comment: Ended up this answer handled an edge case I didn't expect and the other solution couldn't: overlapping records.

Answer (score 1):

So, a given date is active if any of the subcategories on that date is active.
In other words, if at least one subcategory is active, the date is considered active.
If there are no active subcategories on a given date, that date is inactive.
This piece of logic wasn't clear for me in the original question at first.

---

I mentioned an article by Itzik Ben-Gan [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/), which is one way to approach it.

With this approach you can pack all active intervals ignoring inactive intervals completely. The gaps that are left after packing active intervals would be inactive.

If you never have dates that are neither active, nor inactive, this is the final answer.
If you can have such "indefined" dates, things may become tricky.

---

A totally different approach is to use a calendar table (a permanent table, or a series of dates generated on the fly). Join each row of the original table to the calendar table to expand it and make one row for each date in the given interval.

Then group them all by Category and Date and set is_active flag as MAX (if at least one subcategory has is_active=1 for that date, the MAX will be 1, i.e. active as well).

This approach is way more easy to understand and should work reasonably well if the length of intervals is not too long.

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    Calendar.dt
    ,src.cat_id
    ,MAX(src.is_active) AS is_active
    -- we don't even need to know sub_cat_id
FROM
    src
    INNER JOIN Calendar
        ON  Calendar.dt >= src.start_dt
        AND Calendar.dt <= src.end_dt
GROUP BY
    Calendar.dt
    ,src.cat_id
```

So, you'll get one row per date and category. Now you need to merge consecutive dates back into intervals. You can use the Packing Intervals method again or some simpler variation of gaps-and-islands.

**Sample data**

```
WITH src AS
(
    SELECT id,start_dt::date start_dt,end_dt::date end_dt,cat_id,sub_cat_id,is_active,comment
    FROM (VALUES 
        (1,  '2018-01-01', '2018-01-31', 1, 1001, 1, null),
        (2,  '2018-02-01', '2018-02-14', 1, 1001, 0, null),
        (3,  '2018-02-15', '2018-02-28', 1, 1001, 0, 'cat 1 is_active is unchanged despite new record.'),
        (4,  '2018-03-01', '2018-03-30', 1, 1001, 1, null),
        (5,  '2018-01-01', '2018-01-15', 2, 2001, 1, null),
        (6,  '2018-01-01', '2018-01-31', 2, 2002, 1, null),
        (7,  '2018-01-15', '2018-02-10', 2, 2001, 0, 'cat 2 should still be active until 2002 is inactive'),
        (8,  '2018-02-01', '2018-02-14', 2, 2002, 0, 'cat 2 is inactive'),
        (9,  '2018-02-10', '2018-03-15', 2, 2001, 0, 'cat 2 is_active is unchanged despite new record.'),
        (10, '2018-02-15', '2018-03-30', 2, 2002, 1, 'cat 2 should be active agai'),
        (11, '2018-03-15', '2018-03-30', 2, 2001, 1, 'cat 2 is_active is unchanged despite new record.'),
        (12, '2018-04-01', '2018-04-30', 2, 2001, 0, 'cat 2 ends in 0.')
    ) src ( id,start_dt,end_dt,cat_id,sub_cat_id,is_active,comment)
)
,Calendar AS
(
    -- OP Note: Union of all dates from source produced 30% faster results.
    -- OP Note 2: Including the cat_id (which was indexed FK), Made Query 8x faster.
    SELECT cat_id, start_dt dt FROM src
    UNION SELECT cat_id, end_dt dt FROM src 
    /*SELECT dt::date dt
    FROM (
        SELECT MIN(start_dt) min_start, MAX(end_dt) max_end
        FROM src
    ) max_ranges
    CROSS JOIN generate_series(min_start, max_end, '1 day'::interval) dt*/
)
```

**The main query**

Examine result of each intermediate CTE to fully understand how it works.

```
-- expand intervals into individual dates
,CTE_Dates
AS
(
    SELECT
        Calendar.dt
        ,src.cat_id
        ,MAX(src.is_active) AS is_active
        -- we don't even need to know sub_cat_id
    FROM
        src
        INNER JOIN Calendar
            ON  Calendar.dt >= src.start_dt
            AND Calendar.dt <= src.end_dt
            AND Calender.cat_id = src.cat_id
    GROUP BY
        Calendar.dt
        ,src.cat_id
)
-- simple gaps-and-islands
,CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat_id ORDER BY dt) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat_id, is_active ORDER BY dt) AS rn2
    FROM CTE_Dates
)
-- diff of row numbers gives us a group's "ID"
-- condense each island and gap back into interval using simple GROUP BY
SELECT
    MIN(dt) AS start_dt
    ,MAX(dt) AS end_dt
    ,cat_id
    ,is_active
FROM CTE_rn
GROUP BY
    cat_id
    ,is_active
    ,rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY
    cat_id
    ,start_dt
;
```

**Second variant without generic Calendar**

It may perform better, because this variant doesn't have to scan the `src` table (twice) to make a temporary list of dates, sort that list to remove duplicates and then there is no join to that temporary list of dates that most likely doesn't have any supporting index.
But, it generates more rows.

```
-- remove Calendar CTE above, 
-- use generate_series() to generate the exact range of dates we need 
-- without joining to generic Calendar table

-- expand intervals into individual dates
,CTE_Dates
AS
(
    SELECT
        Dates.dt
        ,src.cat_id
        ,MAX(src.is_active) AS is_active
        -- we don't even need to know sub_cat_id
    FROM
        src
        INNER JOIN LATERAL
        (
            SELECT dt::date
            FROM generate_series(src.start_dt, src.end_dt, '1 day'::interval) AS s(dt)
        ) AS Dates ON true
    GROUP BY
        Dates.dt
        ,src.cat_id
)
-- simple gaps-and-islands
,CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat_id ORDER BY dt) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat_id, is_active ORDER BY dt) AS rn2
    FROM CTE_Dates
)
-- diff of row numbers gives us a group's "ID"
-- condense each island and gap back into interval using simple GROUP BY
SELECT
    MIN(dt) AS start_dt
    ,MAX(dt) AS end_dt
    ,cat_id
    ,is_active
FROM CTE_rn
GROUP BY
    cat_id
    ,is_active
    ,rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY
    cat_id
    ,start_dt
;
```

**Result**

```
+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
|  start_dt  |   end_dt   | cat_id | is_active |
+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31 |      1 |         1 |
| 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-28 |      1 |         0 |
| 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-30 |      1 |         1 |
| 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31 |      2 |         1 |
| 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-14 |      2 |         0 |
| 2018-02-15 | 2018-03-30 |      2 |         1 |
| 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-30 |      2 |         0 |
+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

Also, it is known that CTE is an "optimisation barrier" in Postgres, so if you inline these CTEs into a single query its performance may change. You need to test on your system with your data.

Comment: 1) I "postgred" your answer (generate_series is one of these postgre things I didn't know about and exactly why I asked this question).  2) I am going to try to adapt this to my real world scenario to see if it performs better.

Comment: I made one significant change.   Where instead of generating a CTE of all dates, the dates are all distinct possible from the source table.  This ended having a much better performance.

Comment: @DanielGimenez, You'd better test extensively that the query still produces correct results after this change. Try to put all possible corner cases in the test data. One more tweak to try is to join directly to `generate_series(src.start_dt, src.end_dt, '1 day'::interval)` in the `CTE_Dates` and get rid of `Calendar` altogether. That would bring it back to generating a row for each date, but there will be no join to generic Calendar. I added a second variant of the query in the answer. Also, in-lining CTEs may result in different performance.

Comment: I know the first variant worked quite well with production data.   There's about 10 million rows, so I couldn't go over everything, but there were no exceptions for what I did check.

Comment: Using generate_series in the second solution actually produced an out of memory error (I would just remove it).  Also, I modified the first answer and added a key column:  It made the solution more competitive with @untubu's in performance - though still about 3x as slow.

Comment: Ended up the production data had a edge case I didn't expect which was overlapping records.  This solution couldn't handle it.  It would set the end date of the record prior to the overlapper as the end date prior to itself.  Obviously your solution is great given normal data.  It even handled gaps well.